# Mapping and calculating morphometric variables for Alluvial Fans in ArcMap?

Tags: geomorphology

I need to calculate various variables for Alluvial Fans in ArcMap such as Fan area, gradient, angle subtended by fan. The data I am using is SRTM 1 Arc-Second Global. I am attempting to map and measure fans for the first time in ArcMap and would like to understand the way in which I can go about doing this.

Also - should I be using the SRTM Non-Void data instead?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Earth Science SE. This site is different from others. It is not a discussion site. You need to be more specific about your problem. Take a [tour](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site.

Comment: Also, you might get more traction on [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com).